# Affecting a dropdown menu via a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, drop-down-menu

I have a button (".next") and a dropdown ("#page_num"). The dropdown (jquery UI selectmenu) has the following function attached.

```
    $("#page_num").selectmenu ({
        width: 40,
        change:function( event,ui ) {
            search ();
        }
    });;
```

I have the following code where button click causes the dropdown to change to the next option.

```
    $("#next").button();
    $('#page_num').selectmenu();

    $('#next').click(function() { 

        if($("#page_num :selected").index() != $("#page_num option:last-child").index()){
            $("#page_num").val($("#page_num :selected").next().val());
            $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        } else {
            $("#page_num").val($("#page_num option:first-child").val());
            $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    });
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to integrate the former code into the latter. I want the dropdown menu to pass the function "search()" every time the .next button is clicked but have not been able to get this to work. 
Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Instead of trying to combine the dropdown search function with the button I just gave the button its own search function.

```
$("#next").button();
$("#page_num").selectmenu ({
    width: 40,
    change:function( event,ui ) {
        search ();
    }
});

$('#next').click(function() { 

    if($("#page_num :selected").index() != $("#page_num option:last-child").index()){
        $("#page_num").val($("#page_num :selected").next().val());
        $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        search();
    } else {
        $("#page_num").val($("#page_num option:first-child").val());
        $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
    }
});
```

Easier than I had thought!

Comment: Sure thing, it tells me I need to wait until tomorrow before accepting it

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that in both the first code and the second code you're calling selectmenu.  so when you implement the second code, you're overwriting the arguments you sent to selectmenu in the first place (inluding the change handler).

so combine your code like this:

```
$("#next").button();
$("#page_num").selectmenu ({
    width: 40,
    change:function( event,ui ) {
        search ();
    }
});

$('#next').click(function() { 

    if($("#page_num :selected").index() != $("#page_num option:last-child").index()){
        $("#page_num").val($("#page_num :selected").next().val());
        $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
    } else {
        $("#page_num").val($("#page_num option:first-child").val());
        $('#page_num').selectmenu('refresh', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I had tried that already unfortunately. For some reason it changes the dropdown option but still does not pass the search function on the button click.